# Jquery(Autocomplete) return query from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have a small problem that I'm not quite sure what the solution would be.
I'm doing an autoComplete using Jquery, I have a php file that takes the data from the database and leaves it in a format that I need like this in the image below.

http://prntscr.com/hgxjsc

in my html I have the following code

```
<input type="text" id="input_produto" value="" name="input_produto" placeholder="Produto" class="span4 m-wrap">
```

**for better visualization by identation issue**

http://prntscr.com/hgxo8z

Anyone who can help in any way, I'll be grateful, I'm new to this area. If you have an example of how to do it, better yet ... Thank you in advance

*Excuse me, my English is not very good either.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend following these steps in order.

For php code;

```
<?php
//database configuration
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbName = 'codexworld';

//connect with the database
$db = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);

//get search term
$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

//get matched data from skills table
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM skills WHERE skill LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY skill ASC");
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = $row['skill'];
}

//return json data
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

For Jquery code;

```
<script>
   $(function() {
       $( "#skills" ).autocomplete({
          source: 'search.php'
       });
    });
</script>
```

For example Html code;

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="skills">Skills: </label>
  <input id="skills">
</div>
```

Good luck.

Comment: I just forgot to give the return here, I'm sorry. But the problem was solved. Thank you for taking the time to help me. And once again I'm sorry for bad English.